# create listview from object model in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a problem here, I am given JSON data in the form of an object and I want to display it in a listview.
and I've tried displaying JSON data in the form of an array and it worked.
However, in this case I was a bit confused because the JSON data provided was in the form of an object.

> this is when i call the API

```
static Future<Map<String, DataKuliahModel>> getDataKuliah(int smt) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));

    Map<String, DataKuliahModel> finalResult = {};
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/perwalian/get_paket?smt=$smt',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    final result = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
    result.forEach((key, value) {
      DataKuliahModel dataKuliah = DataKuliahModel.fromMap(value);
      finalResult.addAll({
        key: dataKuliah,
      });
    });
    return finalResult;
  }
```

> and this is the model i have

```
class DataKuliahModel {
  DataKuliahModel({
    this.id = '',
    this.idDosen = '',
    this.idMk = '',
    this.nidn,
    this.dosen = '',
    this.idKelasKuliah = '',
    this.kelasKuliah = '',
    this.prodi = '',
    this.kelas = '',
    this.semester = '',
    this.kelompokKelas = '',
    this.kode,
    this.sks = 0,
    this.jumlahKelas = 0,
    this.matakuliah = '',
    this.smt = '',
    this.bobotSks = 0,
    this.rencanaPertemuan = 0,
    this.jenisEvaluasi = '',
  });

  String id;
  String idDosen;
  String idMk;
  dynamic nidn;
  String dosen;
  String idKelasKuliah;
  String kelasKuliah;
  String prodi;
  String kelas;
  String semester;
  String kelompokKelas;
  dynamic kode;
  int sks;
  int jumlahKelas;
  String matakuliah;
  String smt;
  int bobotSks;
  int rencanaPertemuan;
  String jenisEvaluasi;

  factory DataKuliahModel.fromJson(String str) =>
      DataKuliahModel.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory DataKuliahModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DataKuliahModel(
        id: json["id"] ?? '',
        idDosen: json["id_dosen"] ?? '',
        idMk: json["id_mk"] ?? '',
        nidn: json["nidn"],
        dosen: json["dosen"] ?? '',
        idKelasKuliah: json["id_kelas_kuliah"] ?? '',
        kelasKuliah: json["kelas_kuliah"] ?? '',
        prodi: json["prodi"] ?? '',
        kelas: json["kelas"] ?? '',
        semester: json["semester"] ?? '',
        kelompokKelas: json["kelompok_kelas"] ?? '',
        kode: json["kode"],
        sks: json["sks"] ?? 0,
        jumlahKelas: json["jumlah_kelas"] ?? 0,
        matakuliah: json["matakuliah"] ?? '',
        smt: json["smt"] ?? '',
        bobotSks: json["bobot_sks"] ?? 0,
        rencanaPertemuan: json["rencana_pertemuan"] ?? 0,
        jenisEvaluasi: json["jenis_evaluasi"] ?? '',
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "id_dosen": idDosen,
        "id_mk": idMk,
        "nidn": nidn,
        "dosen": dosen,
        "id_kelas_kuliah": idKelasKuliah,
        "kelas_kuliah": kelasKuliah,
        "prodi": prodi,
        "kelas": kelas,
        "semester": semester,
        "kelompok_kelas": kelompokKelas,
        "kode": kode,
        "sks": sks,
        "jumlah_kelas": jumlahKelas,
        "matakuliah": matakuliah,
        "smt": smt,
        "bobot_sks": bobotSks,
        "rencana_pertemuan": rencanaPertemuan,
        "jenis_evaluasi": jenisEvaluasi,
      };
}
```

this is the response given by JSON

[image]

and I tried to initialize here, but got an error whether my writing was wrong
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because your function returns the `Map` but not the `List`.

For example, after parsing you can return the values of the `Map`:

```
static Future<List<DataKuliahModel>> getDataKuliah(int smt) async {
  String url = Constant.baseURL;
  String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));

  Map<String, DataKuliahModel> finalResult = {};
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(
      '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/perwalian/get_paket?smt=$smt',
    ),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    },
  );
  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);
  final result = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
  result.forEach((key, value) {
    DataKuliahModel dataKuliah = DataKuliahModel.fromMap(value);
    finalResult.addAll({
      key: dataKuliah,
    });
  });
  return finalResult.values.toList();
}
```

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sQZng-ML_CUW3iIc8bNkJdJA6KvHiYeR/view?usp=share_link

Comment: You return an array now from your function. You can access to data inside only through the index. Index is int value.